# Whitespace issue in CMD with for /f

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use this code, i.e. drag & drop folder onto the `.bat` file:

```
set FILE_path="%~1"
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (%FILE_path%) do (
  set basename="%%~ni" 
)

echo %basename%
pause 99
```

It should display the folder/file name, but it shows error

> The system cannot find the file.

If I use:

```
for /F "" %%i in (%FILE_path%) do @SET basename=%%~ni
```

then it has problems when file/folder contains white-space. (It doesn't output name after first space).

Comment: Why are you using `for /F` after all? Why not simply using `%~n1`?

Comment: I spotted one of your questions earlier @T.Todua, and have edited some of your questions. I notice your posts have rather a lot of case and spelling errors, especially for a 23K user - I wonder if I could ask you to double-check before posting? Remember that your content is _primarily_ for future users, and volunteer editors will therefore be editing it. It would save them some effort if there was less work to do in the first place (and as a high-rep user you'll be creating a lot of content).

Comment: Some example of misspellings (all missing apostrophes): [63 dont](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2377343%20dont), [36 doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2377343%20doesnt), [34 cant](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2377343%20cant), [7 wont](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2377343%20wont).

Comment: @halfer thank you very much for that. But seems the main problem of my grammar & misspelling is that i don't use the aphostrope with `dont`, `cant` and so on, and I really didn't notice that is was something to be looked over. 
thank you, I'll try not to do them.

Comment: Thanks. A spell-checker will catch two of them; unfortunately, _cant_ and _wont_ are words in their own right (with completely unrelated meanings to _can't_ and _won't_) so you'll just have to be aware of those. Just remember that the apostrophe represents the missing letter "o" in "not", ie "don't" expands to "do not".

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%FILE_path%) do @SET basename="%%~ni"
echo %basename%
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this:

```
@If Not "%~1"=="" (Echo %~n1
    Timeout 99)
```

Based on the code in your question and the answer you've supplied, your version would look more like this:

```
@Echo Off
Set "FilePath=%~1"
For %%A In ("%FilePath%") Do Set "BaseName=%%~nA"
Echo=%BaseName%
Timeout 99
```